# Convert R date from 1/1/2016 to 01/01/2016

Tags: r, date

I have found multiple posts that go from 01/01/2016 to 1/1/2016. I would like to go the other way.

Here is my data set

```
Date    duration   flavor    newDate 
6/4/2016    38  amd64chk    4/6/2016
6/3/2016    873 amd64chk    3/6/2016
6/3/2016    173 amd64chk    3/6/2016
6/3/2016    3383    amd64chk    3/6/2016
6/1/2016    665 amd64chk    1/6/2016
5/26/2016   665 amd64chk    NA
5/25/2016   665 amd64chk    NA
5/24/2016   147 amd64chk    NA
5/24/2016   733 amd64chk    NA
5/24/2016   249 amd64chk    NA
```

**There are two issues here:**

1. The date is only converted when the date is in 1/1/2016 format, once the length increases my code stops working
2. the type of each column is different. Date is "factor" and newDate is "POSIXt"

**Code**

```
df_amd64chk$newDate <- strptime(as.character(df_amd64chk$Date), "%d/%m/%Y")
```

I am rather new to R, so my apologies if this isn't well stated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: If you want to keep it a `Date` class, the only acceptable format is "yyyy-mm-dd", all the rest will keep it a `character`. So in order to convert your vector to a `Date` class you could do `as.Date("4/6/2016", "%d/%m/%Y")`. The `format` argument *always* refers to the original string, not the resulting date.

Comment: @DavidArenburg the date change to 2016/1/1 in my data frame, but the copy paste transforms it 1/1/2016. Do you know why my code stops working when the date length increases?

Comment: Yeah, I haven't noticed that your format is reversed. As I said, you need to pass the format that you have in your original string - not the desired one.

Comment: I just realized what you were saying (with the help of the answer below). Thanks for your response.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The code you provided is almost correct. You may want to try this small modification:

```
df_amd64chk$newDate <- as.Date(df_amd64chk$Date,"%m/%d/%Y")
```

Note that the order of `%m` and `%d` is reversed with respect to the code posted in the OP.

If you aren't interested in preserving a `Date` class, you can convert the output in a character string with another format:

```
df_amd64chk$newDate <- format(as.Date(df_amd64chk$Date,"%m/%d/%Y"),"%m/%d/%Y")
```

This will restore almost the original format, but it will add leading zeros where the month or the day have only one digit.